# Video Playback Time

Tags: python

i have written the code to record the screen frame by frame but after saving the file the video playback is very fast. I want to play the video at normal speed.

The code i tried on ubuntu 16.04

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# windows, mac

# from PIL import ImageGrab

# linux

import pyscreenshot as ImageGrab
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter("output.avi",fourcc,60,(1600,900))

while True:
    # grab fullscreen
    frame = ImageGrab.grab()
    frame = np.array(frame)
    frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    out.write(frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(50)==27:
        break
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: *"i have written the code to record the screen frame by frame"* Nope. If you're lucky, you maybe get 5 screenshots per second. Definitely not *60*. *Of course* the video is "very fast".

Comment: when i use 5 it's look like video is buffering. i want to play the  video just like any screen reocrder software